# How to create Visual Connectable Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

I want to create a Visual connectable web part.

Provider web part contains list view part and consumer web part is a normal User Interface screen which will get `Record ID(Row ID)` of selected row and get detailed information of that Row ID from List and just display information on User Interface.

I have tried unsuccessfully.

Which interface should we inherit (`IWebPartField , IWebPartRow, IWebPartTable , IWebPartParameters`)?

Please see below screen shot for Provider and Consumer  .

**Provider Web Part :** 
[image]

**Consumer Web Part**
[image]